# Facebook iOS sdk, need to press login button twice

Tags: ios, facebook

In my app i am using facebook login. For that below code i have written.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_friends"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

}];
```

but when i am click on fb login but at first time i am not getting callback(handler:^), second time it's calling.

Any one know about this bug or how to resolve it please help me.

Comment: Are you using facebook default button or custom button ?

Comment: using custom button

Comment: Does safari web view for login fired at the 1st click?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SDK 4.16.1 then upgrade to 4.17 solve the problem!